# Using grep in data cleaning in R

Tags: grep

I have a variable with numbers. This numbers are in two formats: with and without a zero before the dot.

For example:

```
a <- c("0.5", ".5", "0.466", ".78")
```

I want to obtain:

```
a <- c("0.5", "0.5", "0.466", "0.78")
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why `grep`? This is a tool for filtering files, not changing them. I would advise `sed` for this:

```
sed -i 's/"\./"0."/g' try.txt
```

Explanation:

```
-i : do the replacement inplace (not in a separate outputfile)
/g : replace all occurence inside the file
try.txt : just the filename
```

The replacement is generally written as:

```
s/replace/by/g
```

In this case:

```
replace : "\.
by      : "0.
```

Why the backslash? Well, `sed` works with so-called "wildcards" (characters with special meaning), a simple dot means "whatever single character". By preceeding it by a backslash I say "It's not a wildcard, it just means the dot character directly after the double quotes".

Comment: I thought I could select those values starting with a dot using grep. and then remplacing the ". by "0.

Comment: @GabrielaCárdenas. That's also possible, but then you still need a tool for doing the replacement. By the way, `grep` is mostly used for showing the line that contains a pattern (`grep <pattern>`) than just the pattern itself (`grep -o <pattern>`).

Answer (score 0):

There:

```
data$var[grep("^\\.",data$var)]<- paste0("0", data$var[grep("^\\.",data$var)])
```